# SDL2 TTF text renders randomly disappearing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, sdl-2

im using SDL2 and just grasped some of the basic-concepts of SDL TTF, but for some reason after a certain amount of time running the app, my text elements disappear with seemingly no reason why, can someone please tell me what i need to do to top my text renders from disappearing? what went wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include "AdviLib.h"

#define SDLKCM SDLK_COMMA
#define SDLKPR SDLK_PERIOD
#define SDLKSP SDLK_SPACE
#define SDLKES SDLK_ESCAPE

void Screenshot(SDL_Renderer* r, const char* name, int w, int h)
{
const uint32_t format{ SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888 };
SDL_Surface* sur{ SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceWithFormat(0, w, h, 32, format) };
SDL_RenderReadPixels(r, NULL, format, sur->pixels, sur->pitch);
SDL_SaveBMP(sur, name);
SDL_FreeSurface(sur);
std::cout << name << " captured!\n";
}

int main(int args, char* argc[])
{
// before SDL init
std::cout << "enter the name of the session: "; string sesh{ sInput() };
std::cout << "enter the name of the local, non .bmp, image: "; string image{ sInput() };

// SDL init
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG | IMG_INIT_PNG);
TTF_Init();
const int W{ 800 }; const int H{ 750 };
SDL_Window* win{ SDL_CreateWindow(sesh.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, W, H, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN) };
SDL_Renderer* ren{ SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC) };
SDL_Surface* img{ IMG_Load(image.c_str()) };
TTF_Font* font{ TTF_OpenFont("CRYSRG__.ttf", 40) };
SDL_Color color{ 205, 99, 35 };
SDL_Texture* tex{ SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, img) };
SDL_Event e;

// buffer variables
string Txt; string Tx2; string Tx3; string Tx4; string Tx5; string Tx6; string Tx7;
SDL_Surface* ts1 = nullptr; SDL_Surface* ts2 = nullptr; SDL_Surface* ts3 = nullptr; SDL_Surface* ts4 = nullptr; SDL_Surface* ts5 = nullptr; SDL_Surface* ts6 = nullptr; SDL_Surface* ts7 = nullptr;
SDL_Texture* tb1 = nullptr; SDL_Texture* tb2 = nullptr; SDL_Texture* tb3 = nullptr; SDL_Texture* tb4 = nullptr; SDL_Texture* tb5 = nullptr; SDL_Texture* tb6 = nullptr; SDL_Texture* tb7 = nullptr;
int w{ img->w }; int h{ img->h }; int x{ randomWithinRange(W - w) }; int y{ randomWithinRange(H - h) };
int tbW{ 0 }; int tbH{ 0 }; int X{ 2 }; int tbY{ 1 }; int tb2Y{ 32 }; int tb3Y{ 63 };  int tb4Y{ 94 }; int tb5Y{ 125 }; int tb6Y{ 156 }; int tb7Y{ 187 };
int ms{ 1 };
bool q{ false };
double ANG{ 0 }; int ANGI{ 0 };

// before main loop

// main loop
while (!q)
{
    // before buffer setup
    SDL_Rect IR{ x, y, w, h };

    // buffer setup
    ANGI = ANG;
    int _TXT_RED = color.r; int _TXT_GRN = color.g; int _TXT_BLU = color.b;
    //current x pos,  current y pos,  current angle,  current speed,  text color red, text color grn, text color blue,
    char buf1[255]; char buf2[255]; char buf3[255]; char buf4[255]; char buf5[255]; char buf6[255]; char buf7[255];
    sprintf_s(buf1, "x: %i", x); sprintf_s(buf2, "y: %i", y); sprintf_s(buf3, "a: %i", ANGI); sprintf_s(buf4, "MS: %i", ms); sprintf_s(buf5, "TR: %i", _TXT_RED); sprintf_s(buf6, "TG: %i", _TXT_GRN);
    sprintf_s(buf7, "TB: %i", _TXT_BLU);
    Txt = buf1; Tx2 = buf2; Tx3 = buf3; Tx4 = buf4; Tx5 = buf5; Tx6 = buf6; Tx7 = buf7;
    ts1 = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, Txt.c_str(), color); ts2 = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, Tx2.c_str(), color); ts3 = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, Tx3.c_str(), color);
    ts4 = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, Tx4.c_str(), color); ts5 = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, Tx5.c_str(), color); ts6 = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, Tx6.c_str(), color);
    ts7 = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, Tx7.c_str(), color);
    tb1 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, ts1); tb2 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, ts2); tb3 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, ts3); tb4 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, ts4);
    tb5 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, ts5); tb6 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, ts6); tb7 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, ts7);
    SDL_QueryTexture(tb1, NULL, NULL, &tbW, &tbH); SDL_QueryTexture(tb2, NULL, NULL, &tbW, &tbH); SDL_QueryTexture(tb3, NULL, NULL, &tbW, &tbH); SDL_QueryTexture(tb4, NULL, NULL, &tbW, &tbH);
    SDL_QueryTexture(tb5, NULL, NULL, &tbW, &tbH); SDL_QueryTexture(tb6, NULL, NULL, &tbW, &tbH); SDL_QueryTexture(tb7, NULL, NULL, &tbW, &tbH);
    SDL_Rect Rct{ X, tbY, tbW, tbH };  SDL_Rect Rc2{ X, tb2Y, tbW, tbH }; SDL_Rect Rc3{ X, tb3Y, tbW, tbH }; SDL_Rect Rc4{ X, tb4Y, tbW, tbH }; SDL_Rect Rc5{ X, tb5Y, tbW, tbH }; SDL_Rect Rc6{ X, tb6Y, tbW, tbH };
    SDL_Rect Rc7{ X, tb7Y, tbW, tbH };

    // set display renders
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(ren, tex, NULL, &IR, ANG, 0, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tb1, NULL, &Rct); SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tb2, NULL, &Rc2); SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tb3, NULL, &Rc3); SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tb4, NULL, &Rc4); SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tb5, NULL, &Rc5);
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tb6, NULL, &Rc6); SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tb7, NULL, &Rc7);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
    {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) q = true;
        else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_w: y -= ms; break; case SDLK_s: y += ms; break;
            case SDLK_a: x -= ms; break; case SDLK_d: x += ms; break;
            case SDLK_r: if (color.r < 255) color.r += 1; else if (color.r == 255) color.r = 0; break;
            case SDLK_g: if (color.g < 255) color.g += 1; else if (color.g == 255) color.g = 0; break;
            case SDLK_b: if (color.b < 255) color.b += 1; else if (color.b == 255) color.b = 0; break;
            case SDLKCM: ANG -= 1; break;
            case SDLKPR: ANG += 1; break;
            case SDLKSP: Screenshot(ren, "capture.bmp", W, H); break;
            case SDLK_q: if (ms > 1) { ms -= 1; /*std::cout << "ms decreased to " << ms << "\n";*/ } /*else if (ms == 1) std::cout << "ms cannot decrease further\n";*/ break;
            case SDLK_e: if (ms < 10) { ms += 1; /*std::cout << "ms increased to " << ms << "\n";*/ } /*else if (ms == 10) ms = 10; std::cout << "ms cannot increase further\n";*/ break;
            case SDLKES: q = true; break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// after main loop - usually nothing

// exit code
SDL_DestroyTexture(tb1); SDL_DestroyTexture(tb2); SDL_DestroyTexture(tb3); SDL_DestroyTexture(tb4); SDL_DestroyTexture(tb5); SDL_DestroyTexture(tb6); SDL_DestroyTexture(tb7); SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
SDL_FreeSurface(ts1); SDL_FreeSurface(ts2); SDL_FreeSurface(ts3); SDL_FreeSurface(ts4); SDL_FreeSurface(ts5); SDL_FreeSurface(ts6); SDL_FreeSurface(ts7); SDL_FreeSurface(img);
TTF_CloseFont(font);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
TTF_Quit();
IMG_Quit();
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you keep loading more textures and surfaces without freeing them. You only need to load them once. Put your buffer setup before the loop, also check the memory usage when its running im almost certain its gonna be rising alot